# 5V DC over data lines

Tags: power-supply, ripple, choke

I am prototyping the below diagram and using the following Common Mode Choke from Murata 50475C (4.7mH DCR 0.7R). When I input a signal on U1 Point B 3Mhz D = 50%, I can see AC coupled signal on U2 point A. However, when I check U2 Point B, I can also see the same signal so I am not sure where the signal is coupling from.

Also, when I use small inductance around 4.7mH I can see a Vripple at Point C around 150mV.

Can anyone explain why it is coupling on the other line? Does the CMC have something to do with it?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What happens if you remove R2, is the signal still coupled to U2 point B? When you write "Also when I use small inductance around 4.7mH I can see a Vripple on Point C around 150mV" so you mean you have added another inductor somewhere else in the circuit? If so, where?

Comment: Are you using twisted pair or simply parallel wires? Parallel wires will often give you crosstalk issues.

Comment: @gbulmer I replace CMC with 4.7mH inductor instead.I remove R2 120R also and still observed the crosstalk. I is it advisable to use inductor instead of CMC? The problem with individual inductor I need low DCR due to voltage drop current is around 200mA.                                     I  use parallel wire on my prototype. I can try to use twisted wire instead and check one more time.

Comment: I was asking to help understanding. I have no more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are transmitting a (differential) signal over a pair of wires, therefore you would see the same signal (phase shifted) on A & B on the receiver input.  If it is not a differential signal, then you need a twisted pair for **each** output pin (4 wires total).  One wire caries the signal, the other is grounded to serve as a shield.

Answer (score 0):

Your common mode chokes will act as a transformer to couple the signals between the two lines.  From the AC point of view U1 (your supply) is a short circuit.  This is OK as your data will be injected differentially.

kevin